# Calculate the difference in year between columns when multiple values are present in one cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

Please guide me on this. I have a following dataframe:

```
df
    dob         date                                         
1   8/11/1966   3/1/1990, 5/1/2000, 8/1/2010
2   6/13/1970   4/1/2014, 3/1/2016, 4/1/2017
3   10/10/2010  4/13/2017
```

My goal is to generate a column showing a difference in years between the 'dob' and 'date' columns like this:

```
df
    dob         date                            difference                  
1   8/11/1966   3/1/1990, 5/1/2000, 8/1/2010    23.570, 23.740, 23.992
2   6/13/1970   4/1/2014, 3/1/2016, 4/1/2017    43.833, 45.751, 46.836
3   10/10/2010  4/13/2017                       6.512
```

Using this following code,

```
diff = (df['date'].sub(df['dob']))/365
diff = (diff / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(float)
df['difference'] = diff.round(3)
```

I was able to calculate the difference when a single date was present but it does not work when there are multiple values in one cell separated by a comma. How can I achieve my goal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Divide up the data in your column. If there are always three dates, the best way it probably to split them into three columns (`df['date1'], df['date2'], df['date3']`). If there are a variable number of dates, you have a problem. You might either split the dates by multiplying rows (create n rows with same data except for date) or apply a python function to each cell (likely to be slow, but you may not care depending on row count).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        dob=['8/11/1996', '6/13/1970'],
        date=[['3/1/1990', '5/1/2000', '8/1/2010'],
              ['4/1/2014', '3/1/2016', '4/1/2017']]
    )).reindex_axis(['dob', 'date'], 1)

l = df.date.str.len()
ilvl0 = df.index.repeat(l)
ilvl1 = np.concatenate(l.apply(np.arange))
date = pd.Series(
    pd.to_datetime(np.concatenate(df.date.values)),
    [ilvl0, ilvl1]
)

difference = date.sub(
    dob, level=0).dt.days.div(365.25).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
df.assign(difference=difference)

         dob                            date            difference
0  8/11/1996  [3/1/1990, 5/1/2000, 8/1/2010]  [-6.45, 3.72, 13.97]
1  6/13/1970  [4/1/2014, 3/1/2016, 4/1/2017]   [43.8, 45.72, 46.8]
```

***OLD ANSWER***

```
date_df = pd.to_datetime(
    pd.DataFrame(df.date.values.tolist(), df.index).stack()
 ).unstack()
```

A little magic and...

```
df.assign(
    difference=date_df.sub(
        pd.to_datetime(df.dob), 0
    ).stack().dt.days.groupby(level=0).apply(list)
)

         dob                            date             difference
0 1996-08-11  [3/1/1990, 5/1/2000, 8/1/2010]    [-2355, 1359, 5103]
1 1970-06-13  [4/1/2014, 3/1/2016, 4/1/2017]  [15998, 16698, 17094]
```

If you want it in years rather than days

```
df.assign(
    difference=date_df.sub(
        pd.to_datetime(df.dob), 0
    ).stack().apply(lambda x: x.days / 365.25).round(2).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
)

         dob                            date            difference
0  8/11/1996  [3/1/1990, 5/1/2000, 8/1/2010]  [-6.45, 3.72, 13.97]
1  6/13/1970  [4/1/2014, 3/1/2016, 4/1/2017]   [43.8, 45.72, 46.8]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since the datatype in my df['date'] is a string instead of the list, what is the best method to change it to list as seen in your dataframe? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @comprocho run this ahead of time     `df.date = df.date.str.split(',\s*')`